# array_merge динамичиские переменные

Tags: php

```
for($i=0;$<$icount;$i++){
$newContent[$i] = array_merge($content[0][$i], $content[1][$i], $content[2][$i], $content[3][$i]);
};
```

Подскажите пжс как можно заменить кол-во элементов в array_merge на автоматичесую подстановку, т.к. их число динамически растет..

Comment: Зачем вы используйте array_merge? Можно подробнее описание задачи?

Comment: В конкретном случае идет слияние 18и массивов в 3. Далее работа с 3мя. Информация типа дата/автор  из разных массивов, соберается по авторам..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используя php5.5 (и выше) можно сделать так:

```
for($i=0;$<$icount;$i++){
    $newContent[] = call_user_func_array(
        'array_merge',
        array_column($content, $i)
    );
}
```

Comment: Да, подправил под себя, всё работает. Спасибо, сам бы не догадался.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо `array_merge` используйте вложенный цикл:

```
for($i=0;$<$icount;$i++){        
   for($j=0;$<$jcount;$j++){
      $newContent[] = $content[$i][$j];
       };
};
```

Ключи для массива `$newContent[]` автоматический генерируется

Comment: идет работа с конкретными ключами, нужно именно  $newContent[0], $newContent[1], $newContent[2], которые включают информацию из старого массива content. Если делать 2 'форлупа' результатом будет только последний массив, а не сумма.